# Concavity test but counter complex number

Tags: calculus

$$ f(x) = -5 \sqrt{x}$$
I want to test the concavity, and I do this
$$ f'(x) = -\frac{5}{2} x^{-1/2}$$ 
$$ f''(x) = -\frac{5}{4} x^{-3/2}$$ 
but if the $x \lt 0$, then $f''(x)$ become complex number, then what should I do?
Thx in advance.

Comment: The function $f(x)$ is only defined for $x\ge 0$. Also, second derivative has sign error.

Comment: In what context do you encounter this problem?  Are you sure that $f$ is not restricted to the positive real line, and that negative values of $x$ are relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a typical calculus course, we are only interested in real-valued functions. Thus $f(x)$ is only *defined* for $x\ge 0$. The first derivative, and higher derivatives, are only defined when $x\gt 0$.

There is a sign issue in your calculation of $f''(x)$ that would affect conclusions about concavity. Note that $f''(x)=\frac{5}{4}x^{-3/2}$.